# iPad UINavigationbar default colour?

Tags: ipad, uinavigationbar, rgb, uinavigationitem

Does anyone know the default colour (in rgb) of the iPad navigationitem? I am building an universal App and want the navbars to be of the same colour.

Comment: Black?  0,0,0 I'm pretty sure that's it.

Comment: I am havin some light gray on my iPad and some deep blue on my iPhone. I want to have the rgb of the light gray color :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit late, but why don't you launch your app on a simulator and screenshot it? Then you could get the color from the image. Here's a gray color I get with my simulator:

```
R: 113 G: 120 B: 128
HEX: #717880
```

Comment: thats the way i did it in the end Hail to the Digital Colormeter :-) But thx anyway